# Polygon construction Do's and don'ts Advice?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I am working on two polygons. One is Forest layer that has the ownership and I have another polygon that has the fire perimeter. I need to build polygon construction to cut out some of them like we need to take out small area like non-forest.

For example, I have the fire perimeter and I need to fire polygon overlay the forest ownership but there are some area that doesn't overlay right. The Line in between non-forest and Forest ownership and I don't want the fire perimeter to over the non-forest but just the forest ownership. Some overlay the private areas that not need to be shown.

[image]

I do not know if this is the right method to clean it up after I contsturct the polygons.

Help ?

You can read this from ArcGIS 10.2 help about it

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Constructing_polygons_from_the_shapes_of_other_features/01m700000012000000/

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.  So, you want to create some polygons that will be used as an erase layer on the Forest and Fire Perimeter layers?  How do you plan on delineating the erase polygons?  You said something about non-forest, but I don't know how you are determining that.  Anything within the Fire Perimeter layer that doesn't intersect the Forest layer?  Really need some clarification and details to be able to answer this question better.

Comment: Since you already post it after I made some changes and I add pictures and hopefully that explains clearly@Baltok

Comment: It's better, but still confusing.  Is the Private land area in your picture just empty space, or is it a polygon that is in the Forest layer but attributed differently?  If it is empty space, I would use Clip to stop the Fire perimeter at the Forest boundary.  If it's a polygon, I would definition query the Private land out and run Clip.  I don't understand why you want to use construct polygons at all.

Comment: No, there are two polygons separate, Forest layer and Fire perimeter. The private land on the Forest layer and it is a polygon showing in white. It is still there and I just change to white. The Fire perimeter is another layer. I wanted the fire perimeter to overlay the forest layer but I need the fire perimeter to not show it in the private land. Get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on PROBERT's comments, I think a good solution is to use a definition query and then the [Clip](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm) tool.

1. For the definition query, you can use the attributes that you are using to symbolize the forest and private land.  Something like:
   [image: Definition Query]
2. Then, run Clip (Analysis) using your Fire Perimeter layer as Input Features and the Forest layer as Clip Features.

The end result should be a Fire Perimeter that only covers Forest areas.